# Tangent space at $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to tangent space at identity matrix

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading a paper, the following is the part of it:

[image]

I can not quite understand the green part.

It seems that every tangent space at an element of $SO(3)$ is isomorphic to the tangent space at the identity element $I$, which is also in $SO(3)$.  And we define this tangent space as the Lie algebra $so(3)$ of the Lie group $SO(3)$.

Could anyone please explain this fact or prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a Lie group and $g\in G$, then the tangent space $T_gG$  at $g$ is canonically isomorphic to the tangent space $T_1G$ at $1$ via
$$(dL_{g^-1})_g:T_gG\to T_1G.$$
Here $L_{g^{-1}}:G\to G$ is left translation by $g^{-1}$ i.e. $a\mapsto g^{-1}a$, and $(dL_{g^-1})_g$ is the differential of $L_{g^{-1}}$ at $g$.

Comment: $1$ here is the identity element of the Lie group $G$? and $a\in G$?

Comment: @sleevechen Yes to both questions.

Comment: For each smooth manifold the tangent spaces at any two points are isomorphic. I think the special feature here is that we have a *canonical* isomorphism induced by a translation.